# How to change the value of a cell in the google sheet based on the sheet name while duplicating the file?

Tags: file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, filenames

I want to duplicate a source file (google sheet) for 100 times in a google drive folder. This is my script:

```
function copyfilefromsource() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet_merge = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
  var last_row = sheet_merge.getLastRow();
  var newsheet_firstname = null;
  var newsheet_surname = null;
  var newsheet_email = null;
  var source_folder = null;
  var file_owner = null;
  var dest_folder = null;
  var sheets_created = 0;
  var new_file = null;
  var source_file = null;
  var employee_id = null;
  var google_domain = null;
  var range = sheet_merge.getRange(1, 1, last_row, 4);
  var temp = null;
  source_file = DriveApp.getFileById(range.getCell(1, 2).getValue()); 
  dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(range.getCell(2, 2).getValue()); 
    file_owner = range.getCell(3, 2).getValue();  
    google_domain = range.getCell(4, 2).getValue();   
  if (last_row <= 6) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No rows to process!");
    return
  }
  for (var i = 7; i <= last_row; i++) { 
    if (range.getCell(i, 4).getValue() == '') {   
    employee_id = range.getCell(i, 1).getValue();       
    newsheet_email =  employee_id + google_domain;  
    newsheet_firstname = range.getCell(i, 2).getValue(); 
    newsheet_surname = range.getCell(i, 3).getValue();  
    new_file = source_file.makeCopy(employee_id, dest_folder);
    new_file.setOwner(file_owner);  
    new_file.addViewer(newsheet_email); 
    new_file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + new_file.getUrl() +'/","'+employee_id+'")');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,4).setValue(new_file.getId());
    sheets_created++; 
    }
  }
  ui.alert(sheets_created + " files were created!")
}

function testFolder(folderName){
  var exist = true;
  try{var testFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName)}
  catch(err){exist=false}
  return exist;
}
```

[image]

The script works perfectly as long as I give the `Employee ID` in `Column A` (shown in the screenshot above) and it will automatically create duplicated files and create a hyperlink for each file in `Column A`.
[image]

The screenshot above is the source file that I want to duplicate for 100 times. However, I want the script able to change the value in cell `B2` to their respective sheet name (based on my script, sheet name = employee ID). Which means, when I opened the 2nd duplicated file, the value in cell `B2` will be `10002` instead of `10001`. When I open 3rd duplicated file, the value in cell `B2` will be `10003` instead of `10001`.

May I know how should I change the value in cell `B2` according to their own sheet name while duplicating the file? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So essentially for each sheet created you want to set its id in the cell `B2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
//...
//after this line of your code : 
new_file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
//add :
var id_ss = new_file.getId();
SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss).getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 2).setValue(employee_id);
```

TIPS : don't take it personal, but your code is a mess.. you might clean it up ;)

Comment: Hi Waxim, thanks for your reply. Sorry for the messy code. I had added the code you provided. However, it shows that `new_file.getSheets` is not a function. This is the error come out when I run the script: `TypeError: new_file.getSheets is not a function` Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: You are right my bad, makeCopy is returning File, not Spreadsheet as I though. I edited my anwser